Extra parameters of Custom Activity Execute
Could you please explain if there is any possibility to extend the parameters which are transfered via POST /execute request when Custom Activity executed?
I would like to receive the Journey Name in the request body on the same level as the Journey identifier - journeyId, not in the inArguments or outArguments section.
I am aware that there is a get method to receive the Journey Name by interaction id GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}, but it seems like extra request when publishing (still consider it as a workaround).
However, maybe anyone has already succeeded to add a journey name to the parameters when executing an activity. Let me know if it's possible (and how)
Thanks

Did you add additional fields in the JSON File? Custom activities in Journey Builder are configured using a config.json file, which defines various properties and arguments, including inArguments and outArguments. These arguments are used to pass data to and from the custom activity

The way to pass it through the in/outArguments is clear. The disadvantage of this solution is that in case of copying / renaming journey the SFMC user must open and save every Custom Activity in the Journey before activating it to override the values from copied journey, so the new Journey name and Interaction id will be relevant. Besides, it's still the optimal option to implement so far. Just wanted to be sure that I don't miss any alternative option.
